# How would I request all these API at once?

Tags: python, multithreading, api

I've looked into threading and running code parallel but I cannot find anything that solves my question. I'm currently trying to attempt to request all these API at the same time, **not one after each other** and then wait for all the responses to return and continue with my code. Can anyone point me towards how I would achieve this?

```
endpoints = [
    "https://catalog.roblox.com/v1/search/items/details?Category=2&limit=30",
    "https://catalog.roblox.com/v1/search/items/details?Category=2&limit=30&cursor=2_1_2167f7d4b3197b431e755ba9c8768abc",
    "https://catalog.roblox.com/v1/search/items/details?Category=2&limit=30&cursor=3_1_199718dc634c5ddba06fb0c047353b03",
    "https://catalog.roblox.com/v1/search/items/details?Category=2&limit=30&cursor=4_1_5d23baeb27732b19291627adb4e71e1d"
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making multiple API calls in parallel using Python (IPython)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982569/making-multiple-api-calls-in-parallel-using-python-ipython)

Comment: I've already tried using this solution but the threads still just wait for the last to end.

Comment: Look here: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/

Comment: @gianni: You should post the code you tried and point out exactly why it doesn't work as you want.

Comment: have you tried grequests: https://pypi.org/project/grequests/